# Borrar una carpeta y su contenido, sin importar que haya dentro. - PHP

Tags: php

quiero simplemente eliminar un directorio en su totalidad.
Para ello hago el uso de rmdir()
Pero al intentar ejecutar esto, no permite el borrado de la carpeta, ya que esta contiene archivos.
Es necesario que recorra el directorio borrando uno por uno los archivos de manera recursiva?
O puedo simplemente eliminar el directorio y ya?
Les dejo el error acá.

```
Warning: rmdir(./adjuntos/): Directory not empty in C:\AppServ\www\gmail\guardarXML.php on line 107
```

Comment: PHP no dispone de una función para eliminar directorios no vacíos, solo queda aceptar alguna de las respuestas o ejecutar un comando del sistema con `shell_exec()`, por ejemplo: `rmdir /Q /S C:\ruta\de\carpeta`

Comment: Siempre veo que usan caracteres durante la execucion de algun comando, ya sea exec, shell_exec, u otro similar.. donde puedo encontrar todos esos y que significan ?

Comment: Los parámetros dependen del sistema operativo, en este caso, Windows: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/rmdir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La sección de contribuciones de la documentación de [rmdir](https://www.php.net/rmdir) contiene una implementación decente de borrado recursivo:

```
function rrmdir($dir) { 
   if (is_dir($dir)) { 
     $objects = scandir($dir);
     foreach ($objects as $object) { 
       if ($object != "." && $object != "..") { 
         if (is_dir($dir. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .$object) && !is_link($dir."/".$object))
           rrmdir($dir. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .$object);
         else
           unlink($dir. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .$object); 
       } 
     }
     rmdir($dir); 
   } 
}
```

Comment: Si esto estaba usando, pero los archivos varían demasiado en su contenido y el tiempo de ejecución varia bastante.  Entonces no puedo llegar y borrar el directorio sin más, debo recorrerlo si o si.. esa es tu respuesta ?

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```
<?php function remove_directory($directory,$patron="*") {
    // validamos si el directorio trae slash al final y lo removemos
    $directory = ($directory[-1] === "/" || $directory[-1] === "\\") ? substr($directory, 0, -1) : $directory;
    // recorremos todos los archivos dentro del directorio
    // glob() nos permite buscar archivos por patron ejemplo:
    foreach(glob($directory . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $patron) as $file) {
        // validamos que sea un directorio
        if(is_dir($file)){
            // eliminamos directorio
            delete_files($file);
        }else{
            // eliminamos archivo
            unlink($file);
        } 
    }
    // eliminamos el directorio raiz
    rmdir($directory); 
}

// eliminams solos los archivos con extension .txt
remove_directory("/home/user1/test/","*.txt")
// eliminams todos los archivos
remove_directory("/home/user1/test")
```

Comment: Entonces no puedo llegar y borrar el directorio sin más, debo recorrerlo si o si.. esa es tu respuesta ?